# Unable to resample between irregular 15 minutes time-stamp 00:14:59 - 00:29:59 in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, time-series, resampling

I have a dataframe 'df' with datetime index set at 15 minute intervals. The intervals are like this

```
Index                Data
2015-03-15 00:14:59  36.0
2015-03-15 00:29:59  54.9
2015-03-15 00:44:59  28.7
```

I want to upsample the above data to minute by minute intervals like below by interpolating the data.

```
Index                Data
2015-03-15 00:14:59  36.0
2015-03-15 00:15:59  36.5
2015-03-15 00:16:59  43.3
...... so on
```

However, I have tried to do following:

```
df = df.resample('T').interpolate(method='spline', order=3)
```

Also tried :

```
df = df.resample('60s').interpolate(method='spline', order=3)
```

However both of the above produce following result. They set the microseconds to 00:00:00 whereas I want it to be set according to the starting timestamp that ends at 59. 00:14:59.

```
Index                Data
2015-03-15 00:14:00  NaN
2015-03-15 00:15:00  NaN
2015-03-15 00:16:00  NaN
...... so on
```

How do I upsample according to uniform intervals of 59 microseconds at the end?

Answer (score 0):

Using`reindex` with `interpolate`

```
df.reindex(pd.date_range(df.index.min(),df.index.max(),freq='T')).interpolate()
```

Comment: No it doesn't work. Still producing NaN.  There is data available only at microsecond date 00:14:59 NOT 00:14:00. so it will produce Nan. Please read the question properly. I want it to be at intervals of 00:14:59, 00:15:59 @WeNYoBen

Answer (score 0):

Solution from WeNYoBen will generate valeus at needed intervals id the Index column has been indexed. If not, the below formula will generate the values. `pd.date_range(df['Index'].iloc[0],df['Index'].iloc[-1],freq='T')`
this will provide the values as follows`['2015-03-15 00:14:59', '2015-03-15 00:15:59',
               '2015-03-15 00:16:59', '2015-03-15 00:17:59',
               '2015-03-15 00:18:59', '2015-03-15 00:19:59',
               '2015-03-15 00:20:59', '2015-03-15 00:21:59',
               '2015-03-15 00:22:59', '2015-03-15 00:23:59',
               '2015-03-15 00:24:59', '2015-03-15 00:25:59',
               '2015-03-15 00:26:59', '2015-03-15 00:27:59',
               '2015-03-15 00:28:59', '2015-03-15 00:29:59',
               '2015-03-15 00:30:59', '2015-03-15 00:31:59',
               '2015-03-15 00:32:59', '2015-03-15 00:33:59',
               '2015-03-15 00:34:59', '2015-03-15 00:35:59',
               '2015-03-15 00:36:59', '2015-03-15 00:37:59',
               '2015-03-15 00:38:59', '2015-03-15 00:39:59',
               '2015-03-15 00:40:59', '2015-03-15 00:41:59',
               '2015-03-15 00:42:59', '2015-03-15 00:43:59',
               '2015-03-15 00:44:59']` But re-indexing is not working for me! May be you can figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
df = df.asfreq('60s').interpolate()
```